# Conditional expectation from joint distribution

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

I am new to probability and trying to convince myself of the correctness of the equations in [this paper](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/zoubin/papers/tr-96-1.pdf) on factor analysis. There is a step I am missing. I'll give my understanding so far and then highlight the question below.

Given a $p$-dimensional vector $\textbf{x}$ modeled using a $k$-dimensional factor $\textbf{z}$ where typically $k < p$, the model for factor analysis is:

$$
\textbf{x} = \Lambda \textbf{z} + \textbf{u}
$$

Where $\Lambda$ is a matrix, $\textbf{u} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \Psi)$, and $\textbf{z} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I)$. This means $\textbf{x} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \Lambda \Lambda^{\top} + \Psi)$ because:

$$
\begin{align}
\textbf{x}
&= \Lambda \textbf{z} + \textbf{u}
\\
&= \Lambda \mathcal{N}(0, I_k) + \mathcal{N}(0, \Psi)
\\
&= \mathcal{N}(0, \Lambda \Lambda^{\top} + \Psi)
\end{align}
$$

Now, we have the joint distribution:

$$
P\bigg(
\begin{bmatrix}
\textbf{x} \\ \textbf{z}
\end{bmatrix}
\bigg)
=
\mathcal{N}\bigg(
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
,
\begin{bmatrix}
\Lambda \Lambda^{\top} + \Psi & \Lambda
\\
\Lambda^{\top} & I \end{bmatrix}
\bigg)
$$

I can convince myself that this is correct and fairly easily. $\text{Var}(\textbf{x})$ and $\text{Var}(\textbf{z})$ come from their definitions, while $\text{Cov}(\textbf{x}, \textbf{z})$ and $\text{Cov}(\textbf{z}, \textbf{x})$ are easy enough to compute, e.g.:

$$
\begin{align}
\text{Cov}(\textbf{x}, \textbf{z})
&= \mathbb{E}[(\textbf{x} - \mathbb{E}[\textbf{x}])(\textbf{z} - \mathbb{E}[\textbf{z}])^{\top}]
\\
&= \mathbb{E}[(\textbf{x} - 0)(\textbf{z} - 0)^{\top}]
\\
&= \mathbb{E}[(\Lambda \textbf{z} + \textbf{u})(\textbf{z})^{\top}]
\\
&= \mathbb{E}[\Lambda \textbf{z} \textbf{z}^{\top} + \textbf{u} \textbf{z}^{\top}]
\\
&= \Lambda \mathbb{E}[\textbf{z} \textbf{z}^{\top}] + \mathbb{E}[\textbf{u} \textbf{z}^{\top}]
\\
&= \Lambda
\end{align}
$$

Where $\mathbb{E}[\textbf{u} \textbf{z}^{\top}] = \mathbb{E}[\textbf{u}]\mathbb{E}[\textbf{z}^{\top}] = 0 \cdot 0$ and $\mathbb{E}[\textbf{z}\textbf{z}^{\top}] = I_k$ because:

$$
\begin{align}
\text{Var}(\textbf{z})
&= \mathbb{E}[\textbf{z}\textbf{z}^{\top}] + \mathbb{E}[\textbf{z}] \mathbb{E}[\textbf{z}]^{\top}
\\
I_k &= \mathbb{E}[\textbf{z}\textbf{z}^{\top}] + 0
\end{align}
$$

So far so good.

### Question

The authors then claim that the conditional expectation of the first and second moments of the factors are:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\textbf{z} \mid \textbf{x}] &= \Lambda^{\top} (\Psi + \Lambda \Lambda^{\top})^{-1} \textbf{x}
\\
\\
\mathbb{E}[\textbf{z} \textbf{z}^{\top} \mid \textbf{x}] &= I_k - (\Lambda^{\top} \Psi + \Lambda \Lambda^{\top})^{-1} \Lambda + \Lambda^{\top} (\Psi + \Lambda \Lambda^{\top})^{-1} \Lambda^{\top} \textbf{x} \textbf{x}^{\top} ((\Psi + \Lambda \Lambda^{\top})^{-1})^{\top} 
\end{align}
$$

The authors claim that this comes from "the joint normality of data and factors". How was this computed? I've gone through the Wikipedia page on conditional expectation, but I don't see anything that defines it in terms of the joint distribution or conditional distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this is an important property of Gaussian distribution and it is frequently used. Suppose
$$
P\bigg(
\begin{bmatrix}
{x}_1 \\ {x}_2
\end{bmatrix}
\bigg)
=
\mathcal{N}\bigg(
\begin{bmatrix} \mu_1 \\ \mu_2 \end{bmatrix}
,
\begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma_{11} & \Sigma_{12}
\\
\Sigma_{21} & \Sigma_{22} \end{bmatrix}
\bigg).
$$
Then the conditional distribution of $x_1$ given $x_2$ is
$$
P(x_1|x_2) = \mathcal{N}(\mu_1 + \Sigma_{12}\Sigma_{22}^{-1}(x_2-\mu_2),\Sigma_{11} - \Sigma_{12}\Sigma_{22}^{-1}\Sigma_{21}).
$$
Therefore we have the conditional expectation as you give, because in this case,
$$
\Sigma_{11} = \Lambda\Lambda^{\top} + \Psi, \Sigma_{12} = \Lambda,\Sigma_{22} = I,\mu_1 = \mu_2 = 0.
$$
For the second quantity, just use the fact that
$$
\mathbb{E}[\textbf{z} \textbf{z}^{\top} \mid \textbf{x}] = \mathbb{E}[z|x](\mathbb{E}[z|x])^{\top} + {\rm Var}(z|x).
$$

Comment: Is the conditional expectation of a conditional probability density just the mean of that density?

Comment: Yes, you are right ^_^

Comment: Sorry for the delayed acceptance. I was AFAIK and didn't immediately see the derivation because I actually need $p(x_2 | x_1)$. For others, that conditional density and the one above are both defined in the Matrix Cookbook: https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf, section 8.1.3.

Comment: Never mind that. What really matters is that you got some helpful ideas on your questions. ^_^ BTW, nice references, thanks!